# Python: get itertools.combinations to return progressively larger combinations

Tags: python, python-2.7, combinatorics, python-itertools

Right now I am using:

```
list_one = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10))
list_two = []
print "List One: " + str(list_one)
for i in range(0, 5):
        list_two = tuple(c for i in range(len(list_one))
                           for c in itertools.combinations(list_one[:i], i))
print "List Two: " + str(list_two)
```

which outputs:

```
List One: ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10))
List Two: ((), ((1, 2),), ((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)))
```

What I want is:

```
List One: ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10))
List Two: ((), ((1, 2),), ((3, 4),), ((5, 6),), ((7, 8),), ((9, 10),), ((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (5, 6)), ((1, 2), (7, 8)), ((1, 2), (9, 10)), ((3, 4), (5, 6)), ((3, 4), (7, 8)) ...
```

So the first round will be single items
The second pass includes all 2 item combinations including (1, 2), etc.
The third pass includes all 3 item combinations including (1, 2) and (3, 4), etc.

A simplified version:

```
list_one = ((1), (2), (3), (4), (5))
```

would output:

```
((1), (2), (3), (4), (5), ((1), (2)), ((1), (3)), ((1), (4)), ((1), (5)), ((2), (3)), ((2), (4))... ((3), (4), (5)))
```

How to modify so that it is moving from:
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
1,2 -> 1,3 -> 1,4 -> 1,5
...

Comment: ...I handcoded my desired outputs, so if there is a flaw in the combinations, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get rid of `[:i]`:

```
import itertools

list_one = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10))
list_two = []
print "List One: " + str(list_one)
for i in range(0, 5):
    list_two = tuple(c for i in range(len(list_one))
                     for c in itertools.combinations(list_one, i))
print "List Two: " + str(list_two)
```

Output:

```
List One: ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10))
List Two: ((), ((1, 2),), ((3, 4),), ((5, 6),), ((7, 8),), ((9, 10),), ((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (5, 6)), ((1, 2), (7, 8)), ((1, 2), (9, 10)), ((3, 4), (5, 6)), ((3, 4), (7, 8)), ((3, 4), (9, 10)), ((5, 6), (7, 8)), ((5, 6), (9, 10)), ((7, 8), (9, 10)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (7, 8)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (9, 10)), ((1, 2), (5, 6), (7, 8)), ((1, 2), (5, 6), (9, 10)), ((1, 2), (7, 8), (9, 10)), ((3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)), ((3, 4), (5, 6), (9, 10)), ((3, 4), (7, 8), (9, 10)), ((5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (9, 10)), ((1, 2), (3, 4), (7, 8), (9, 10)), ((1, 2), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)), ((3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)))
```

Comment: Just figured that out. If this question wasn't upvoted or answered, I'd have deleted it. But you'll still get your darn answer :) Thanks.